# Visual Studio IDE - is there a way to open the console window at a particular location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When running/debugging an application, I would like the output console window to open on the right side of the code/editor window automatically. At present, I do it manually by following the three steps:

Step 1.

Setup the code window to occupy only the left side of the screen like so:

[image]

Step 2.

Start the debugging/run session which open the console window at some arbitrary position like so

[image]

Note in picture that the breakpoint in the code window has been hit and behind this window is the console window.

Step 3.

Manually navigate to the console window and position it up to occupy the right half of the screen like so:

[image]

Is there a way to configure/set these window positions automatically and have Visual Studio remember this setting from session to session?

Comment: As an alternative, there is a [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019) window within Visual Studio itself that you could drag up and split vertically, all within Visual Studio

Comment: I have "Developer Power Shell", which your link says is more powerful. Is there a way to start a debugging session, by pressing F5 and have the output appear in the Developer Power shell tab within the IDE itself instead of a separate window that opens up now completely independent of the code editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default start-up position (and size) for Visual Studio's debug console window by right-clicking in its title bar, selecting the "Properties" command from the menu and, in the displayed pop-up, uncheck the "Let system position window" box:

[image]

The values in the "Size" and "Position" edit boxes will be set to their *current* values; so, you would most likely want to set up the size and position of the console *before* unchecking that option.

Comment: Ah indeed. This would also work. Does this setting remain session through session? i.e., Does VS remember this even after restarting the computer?

Comment: It's a Windows setting, so it will remain across VS sessions ... let me restart my PC and I'll get back to you ...

Comment: Hmm...I am not sure what it means to say it is a system wide setting. I just made this setting apply to the console window that opens up when I hit F5 inside of Visual Studio IDE. Then, I restarted the debugging session and the console windows indeed open up on the right hand side as I want. Then, I went to the command bar and ran `cmd`. This opens a console at a different location.

Comment: @Tryer Interesting (and I can confirm) - I guess VS uses its 'own' console (the clue's in the title bar name: *Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console*). I would also bet good money on the fact that it won't change settings for other users. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Tryer ... and, yes, the settings are saved across a PC restart.

Comment: Ah...well I'll be. There is just so much to Visual Studio...Currently useing the 2022 version and so far so good.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Indeed, this was my first IDE. So, I have special affection for it. Everyone kept mocking this saying VIM is better, this is a memory hog, etc. I tried very hard to get VIM working for me. Perhaps it is me, but VIM just would not work for me. Something or the other was always amiss. I am now back to VS IDE and VSCode.

Comment: @Tryer I have to agree. The 2022 version is 64bit...and I do notice it being faster in almost every regard.